# How can I fix this toString() method?

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I am trying to use  toString() method , but somehow doesn't work, instead of getting the actual values ( name and numbers of student) I am getting this :

```
================= students list =====================

----------------------
com.se.classes.Student@4554617c
com.se.classes.Student@74a14482
com.se.classes.Student@1540e19d
===============================================
```

This is the method in the com.se.classes :

```
public String toString() {
    s = "\n================= students list =====================\n";
    s = s + "\n----------------------";
    for (int i = 0; i < nb; i++) 
    s = s + "\n" + student[i];
    s = s + "\n===============================================";
    return s;
}
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: `javascript !== java`!

Comment: What's the expected output anyway? And what's this `Student` class?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I print my Java object without getting "SomeType@2f92e0f4"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4)

Comment: You see the default implementation of the Student class. This includes the class name and the internal address of the object. You can override the toString method in Student class if you want a different behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a toString() function to your Student class. I would do this for you but you have not posted the Student class. Feel free to and I will update with an example.

Here is an assumed Student class.

```java
    static class Classroom {

        private static final String HEADER = "================= students list =====================";

        private static final String FOOTER = "=====================================================";

        private final Student[] students;

        Classroom(Student[] students) {
            this.students = students;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(HEADER).append("\n");

            for (Student student : students) {
                builder.append(student).append("\n");
            }
            return builder.append(FOOTER).toString();
        }

    }

    static class Student {

        private final String name;

        public Student(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("name=%s", name);
        }
    }
```

## Test

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student[] students = new Student[] {
                new Student("Foo"),
                new Student("Bar")
        };

        Classroom classroom = new Classroom(students);

        System.out.println(classroom);
    }
```

## Output

```
================= students list =====================
name=Foo
name=Bar
=====================================================
```

Comment: Not the one who downvoted, but I'm guessing it's because this is a fairly common duplicate question that should be flagged as such instead of answered.

Comment: Hmm, that is understandable!

Answer (score 0):

This example in case you do not want (or can't) to add `toString()` method to `Student` class directly:

```
class Student {
    private final String firstName;  // John
    private final String lastName;   // Doe

    // getters
}

static String toString(String[] students) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    buf.append("================= students list =====================\n");

    for(Student student : students) {
        buf.append(student.getFirstName()).append(' ').append(studnet.getLastName);  // John Doe
        buf.append("\n----------------------");     
    }   

    return buf.tpString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Student class needs a toString() too.  Also your toString is inefficient:

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(System.lineSeparator())
                          .append("================= students list =====================")
                          .append(System.lineSeparator())
                          .append(System.lineSeparator())
                          .append("----------------------";
    for (int i = 0; i < nb; i++) 
        s.append(System.lineSeparator())
         .append(student[i]);

    s.append(System.lineSeparator())
     .append("===============================================");

   return s.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you !!! it works.